# Why is it true that: $f(\xi) = \dfrac{\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a ^b g(x)dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Why is it true that $\exists \xi \in [a,b]$ such that:

$f(\xi) = \dfrac{\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a ^b g(x)dx}$

Does $\int_a ^b g(x)dx$ "act" as the $(b-a)$ in the mean value theorem for integrals?

Comment: This is true only when $g$ doesn't change sign in the interval.

Comment: And observe that $f$ is continious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: WLoG suppose that $g> 0$ on $[a,b]$, and make use of intermediate value theorem with observing
$$
min\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}=m\le\dfrac{\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a ^b g(x)dx}\le M=max\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}
$$